# Palabras para antepasados lejanos

Tags: selección-de-palabras, parentesco, genealogía

Dada mi reciente afición por los árboles genealógicos, me veo con la duda de saber cuál es la forma correcta de referirse a los antepasados de uno más allá de la cuarta generación. Hasta ahora, tengo las siguientes opciones:

**La "de toda la vida":**

> 4ª generación: tatarabuelo
>
> 5ª generación: tatara-tatarabuelo (no sé si con o sin guión)
>
> 6ª generación: tatara-tatara-tatarabuelo
>
> ...

**La "base 4":**

> 4ª generación: tatarabuelo
>
> 5ª generación: padre de tatarabuelo
>
> ...
>
> 8ª generación: tatarabuelo de tatarabuelo
>
> 9ª generación: padre de tatarabuelo de tatarabuelo
>
> ...

**La "directa":**

> 4ª generación: tatarabuelo
>
> 5ª generación: ancestro directo (5 generaciones)
>
> 6ª generación: ancestro directo (6 generaciones)
>
> ...

La primera supongo que es como la versión inglesa *great-great-great-grandfather*. Fácil de aprender pero liosa cuando te vas muy para atrás. La segunda opción me parece fácil de usar como una especie de sistema de numeración en base 4, pero también difícil si te vas aún más para atrás (abuelo de tatarabuelo de tatarabuelo de tatarabuelo de...). Es la que uso yo principalmente cuando hablo con otras personas acerca de mi árbol. La tercera opción me parece la más simple y directa, útil para cualquier número de generaciones atrás, pero pierde la gracia de usar términos específicos. Es la que usa, por ejemplo, la web de MyHeritage donde tengo mi árbol.

¿Cuál es la forma recomendada? Y como extra, ¿hay palabras en español para referirse a antepasados anteriores al tatarabuelo? Ya sea que hayan caído en desuso o sean completamente desconocidas...

Comment: Si te gusta la genealogía, ¡creo que te gustará [genealogy.se]!

Comment: Por una vez, parece que yahoo respuestas ofrece referencias ricas: [¿Cómo se le llama al papá de el tatarabuelo, y al papá de este?](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061209205419AAZZ0C4), lo que nos lleva a la Guía genealógica y su [vocabulario en genealogía (punto 10)](http://www.genealogia-es.com/guia3.html) con su _antepasado de Xª generación_.

Comment: @fedorqui Me ha gustado la propuesta de "bisabuelo, tresabuelo, cuatriabuelo, pentabuelo, etc...", lo único que me resulta raro es que el prefijo va descoordinado con el número de generación que representan: "pentabuelo = antepasado de sexta generación". ¡Y gracias por la referencia al foro de genealogía, le echaré un vistazo!

Comment: La única palabra que conozco que pasa del *tatara-* es *chozno*, el hijo del tataranieto. Ignoro si hay equivalente en el otro sentido.

Comment: En wikipedia mencionan que el (grado 5) padre del tatarabuelo se llama **Trastatarabuelo** o **cuarto abuelo** https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nomenclatura_de_parentesco_en_espa%C3%B1ol

Comment: Acerca de _cuál es la forma recomendada_: yo creo que ninguna. Cualquier grado de _tátara_ me parece incómodo y es poco probable que alguien lo necesite en realidad. Y si es para asuntos técnicos, como las genealogías, es mucho más útil (creo yo) decir "el antecesor número cinco". (Reconozco que este comentario es aburrido y un poco de perogrullo).

Comment: Yo conocía que a la quinta generación de le decía chozno por un comentario que me hicieron hace años, pero no lo he vuelto a escuchar. Parece que las descedecias no llegan a tanto, pero ahora con la prolongación de los años que nos está dando la vida no va a ser extraño que ese termino tome vigencia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque solo llega al grado 5 de parentesco la respuesta que buscas la tiene wikipedia en el articulo [Anexo:Nomenclatura de parentesco en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nomenclatura_de_parentesco_en_espa%C3%B1ol)

Si alguien encuentra un nombre específico para el 6 grado tal vez lo puede aportar aquí y también al artículo de wikipedia.

Cito la tabla de contenido del artículo.

> 2  Parientes consanguíneos de ego
>
> 2.1    Ascendencia de ego en línea directa
>
> 2.1.1  Padres
>
> 2.1.2  Abuelos
>
> 2.1.3  Bisabuelos
>
> 2.1.4  Tatarabuelos
>
> [2.1.5 Trastatarabuelos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nomenclatura_de_parentesco_en_espa%C3%B1ol#Trastatarabuelos)
>
> 2.2    Descendencia de ego en línea directa
>
> 2.2.1  Hijos
>
> 2.2.2  Nietos
>
> 2.2.3  Bisnietos
>
> 2.2.4  Tataranietos
>
> 2.2.5  Trastataranietos, [choznos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=91AUweV) o cuadrinietos
>
> [2.2.6 Bichoznos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nomenclatura_de_parentesco_en_espa%C3%B1ol#Bichoznos)

Comment: ¿Alguien más leyó "Bizcochos" en 2.2.6?

Comment: No @fedorqui. Seguro estas a dieta y la imaginación te jugó una mala pasada. ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, desconocía estos términos. Sin embargo, los únicos que aparecen en la RAE son _chozno_ y _bichozno_. Hacia arriba no aparece ninguno, como _trastatarabuelo_. Sin embargo, es curioso que, al parecer, "tatara" es una corrupción de "trastras".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo curioso esto último que comentas. Y tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: @fedorqui me baso en la definición de _tataranieto_ de la RAE, dice que viene de "tras-" y "trasnieto". Así que supongo que al principio "bisnieto" se decía "trasnieto" (tras el nieto), y el siguiente sería el que va tras el trasnieto, el "trastrasnieto", de ahí "tataranieto".

Comment: @fedorqui más curioso aún: según el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios), la palabra _chozno_ significaba "tataranieto" hasta el diccionario de 1817, e "hijo del tataranieto" a partir del diccionario de 1884. La palabra _bichozno_ sólo existe a partir del diccionario de 1925.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo interesantísimo. Además, no conocía este recurso, por lo que lo añado a [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674)