# ¿Cómo se escribe una cadena de "tatara-"?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, acentuación, prefijos, parentesco

Gracias a la pregunta [Palabras para antepasados lejanos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17144/palabras-para-antepasados-lejanos), sabemos que la palabra para el padre del tatarabuelo sería, en teoría, *trastatarabuelo*.
La explicación es que el *tatara-* de *tataranieto* (del cual surge *tatarabuelo* por imitación) se formó a base de aplicar *tras-* al antiguo *trasnieto*, resultando un *trastras-* que terminó transformándose en *tatara-*.

Ahora bien, siguiendo la misma lógica de prefijar con *tras-*, el término para el padre del **tras**tatarabuelo sería... **trastras**tatarabuelo. Nos encontramos con el mismo *trastras-* inicial que hoy en día se dice *tatara-*. Por tanto se comprende que tanta gente, incluido el OP de la pregunta arriba indicada, acudan al recurso de repetir varias veces ese *tatara-* para referirse a un antepasado lejano: *Este collar perteneció a mi tatara-tatara-tatara...*

Y aquí surge la duda: **¿cómo se escribe una cadena de **tátaras*?**

- ¿Con [guión](https://twitter.com/perezreverte/status/905819439840600065) y sin tilde, como el OP de la pregunta de arriba?

  > 5ª generación: **tatara-tatarabuelo** (no sé si con o sin guión)
- ¿Sin guión y sin tilde, atendiendo a la duda que OP se planteaba en la pregunta y a la lógica descrita en la respuesta?

  > tatarabuelo → trastatarabuelo → **tataratatarabuelo** → trastataratatarabuelo → ...
- ¿Con guión y con tilde, atendiendo a la pronunciación, como en [este artículo](http://www.elmundo.es/cronica/2018/06/26/5b2fc1f4e5fdea03498b466c.html) de EL MUNDO?

  > Su **tátara-tatarabuelo**, Manuel Núñez de Villavicencio, nacido en La Laguna (Tenerife), fue uno de los pasajeros del *Santísimo Sacramento*, la primera fragata de colonos canarios que llegó a Luisiana.
- ¿Con tilde pero separando con espacios, como en algunos de los [ejemplos de Reverso](http://context.reverso.net/traduccion/espanol-frances/t%C3%A1tara+tatarabuelo)?

  > Pero lo que mi **tátara tátara tátara tátara tátara tátara tatarabuelo** no sabía era que la guerra solo era una distracción.
- ¿Sin tilde y separando con comas, como en alguno de los [ejemplos de Glosbe](https://es.glosbe.com/es/ca/tatarabuelo)?

  > Mi madre solía contarme historias de mi **tatara, tatara tatara, tatara, tatara, tatarabuelo**, que creció en un campo de concentración durante la Segunda Guerra Mundial.

Cabe destacar que el DLE no recoge ni [**tatara-*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tatara-) o [**tátara-*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=t%C3%A1tara-) como prefijos, ni [**tátara*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=t%C3%A1tara) o [**tatara*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tatara) como palabras, por lo que no es de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es interesante el [capítulo 10.4 de la Nueva Gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=futpcotRaxBaJzyD) de la RAE, que empieza hablando de la recursividad de los prefijos. Cita los casos de los prefijos *anti-* (antiantisemita), *contra-* (contracontraprogramar) y otros, en el párrafo 10.4c trata precisamente del que ocupa tu pregunta:

> Para prolongar retrospectivamente la serie *abuelo, bisabuelo, tatarabuelo* [...] se repite en la lengua coloquial de muchos países hispanohablantes el pseudoprefijo *tatara-*, a veces en alternancia con *re-* o *requete-*.

Cita textos con los casos de *tataratatarabuelo* y *tataratataranieto*. Sin embargo, previamente en el párrafo 10.4a se comenta lo siguiente:

> Como se ve en los ejemplos, en estos casos de recursividad se documentan tanto expresiones con guion entre el prefijo y su base como formaciones escritas sin él.

Un ejemplo que documenta es:

> [...] porque este les acusaba de haber cometido una calumnia, y así sucesivamente, desembocando todo ello en una inacabable serie de querellas, contraquerellas, contra-contra-querellas, etc.

Por tanto, entiendo que las formas aceptables serían *tataratatarabuelo* y *tatara-tatarabuelo*, con guion y sin guion, pero no así las formas que tratan *tátara* o *tatara* como palabras sueltas, dado que estas palabras por sí solas no tienen sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Llego por azar y "un poco" tarde, y me estreno reviviendo este hilo.

El hijo del tataranieto es **chozno**; me sorprende que nadie lo haya dicho. Hacia atrás, después de tatarabuelo se puede decir trastatarabuelo o, mejor en mi opinión y para no alargar, **cuarto abuelo**; para la siguiente generación, están el **quinto abuelo** y el  **bichozno** o **bischozno** o **quinto nieto**; luego el **sexto abuelo** y el **sexto nieto**, y así sucesivamente.

La curiosidad me llevó al DLE que no incluye el "bizchono", pero en el bichozno habla del cuadrinieto; sin embargo, me quedo con la que conocía: cuarto nieto, más aún porque después se complicaría: ¿quintinieto o pentanieto?

Comment: Buena contribución, aunque la pregunta es cómo escribir una cadena de "tataras". Conocer esas otras opciones está bien, pero el objetivo de la pregunta es responder a este caso específico, aunque sea como inquietud académica o teórica, más que práctica.

Comment: Después de agregar el parrafo del cuadrinieto, veo el comentario de Diego. No quise decirlo antes, pero está implícito en lo escrito: si hay una manera correcta y más sencilla, ¿qué interés tiene una forma que no es conocida ni registrada en el DLE, y que parece más un trabalenguas?